# Дублируется запрос к базе данных

Tags: php

Есть такое подлючение к бд:

```
<?php
 namespace Engine\connectBd;
class database
{
public $name;
public $host;
public $password;
public $bdname;
public $dbNames =[];

 public function __construct($host,$name,$password,$bdname){
    $this->name =$name;
    $this->host=$host;
    $this->password=$password;
    $this->bdname=$bdname;
}

public function connect($connectName){

    $name =$connectName;
    $connectName = mysqli_connect("$this->host", "$this->name","$this->password","$this->bdname");
    $this->bdNames["$name"] = $connectName;
    return  $this->bdNames["$name"];
}
```

Место где производится запрос к бд

```
<?php
namespace Engine;
use Engine\connectBd\database;

class cms
{
public function run(){ //ПИСАТЬ ЧТОБЫ ОТОБРАЖАЛОСЬ НА САЙТЕ СЮДА запускает все, что тут написано.
    
    $db = new database('localhost','root','','magazin');
    $connect=$db->connect('connect');
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO test(id,id2,id3) values(1,2,3)");

}
}
```

Тут запрос выполняется два раза, почему?

Так же есть файл, который запускает это все, но вроде дело не в нем

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Engine\cms;
try {
$cms = new cms();
$cms->run();
}catch (\Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте по логам веб-сервера, сколько точно раз вы вызвали этот скрипт.

Comment: Запрос за фавиконом также дергает index.php или че там мордой служит.

Comment: По 2 get запроса из одно проекта первый так выглядит  -  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, второй так   -  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://lastmineproject/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: есть 1 файл еще index.php, но там только подклчючение последнего примера, где фукнция run, ,больше файлов нет

Comment: Настройки твоего веб-сервера редиректят все запросы (в том числе и тот что идет за фавиконом) на файл index.php. Соответственно, надо подкрутить веб-сервер чтобы за фавиконом отдельно ходил. Проблема эта не новая, в инете куча ответов.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] типо это?

Comment: @СергейАкимов mysqli_query инициирует отправку одного запроса к БД. Если по логике Вашего приложение на каких-то http-запросах не нужно выполнять SQL-запрос, то напишите код так, чтобы `query` попросту не вызывался. Организуйте роутинг.
Должен ли сервер запускать интерпретатор PHP если не найден favicon.ico - решать вам. Лично я не вижу необходимости дергать PHP когда статика (иконки, картинки) статичны (исключение - когда надо нарезать размеры на лету).

Comment: В класс database добавить св-во $statement и проверять наличие коннекта через него